# How to opt-in to TypeScript's strictPropertyInitialization on a per-file basis?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to opt-in to TypeScript's strictPropertyInitialization on a per-file basis?

Comment: Opting out per-file could also be good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We cannot opt-in to TypeScript's [`strictPropertyInitialization`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html#compiler-options) on a per-file basis, because it is a type-checking compile flag, and overriding a type-checking compile flag on a per-file basis is not possible. [This issue requested](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8405) that feature in April 2016, and the TypeScript team closed the issue as "too complex". The comments in the issue offer an explanation and several workarounds.